# Math.ceil in angularjs returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, math

When I run `Math.ceil(-0.001)` via console it returns `-0`, which 
also corresponds to the offical [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil).

But if I'm running `Math.ceil(-0.001)` in my **angularjs** project, it 
returns `0`, which is actually not correct.

I wanted to seperate the digits between the comma, that's why I faced this problem.

Comment: Note that the MDN is not "official" - it's community edited, but the described behaviour is mandated in [the official spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.6).

Comment: I tried it into an angular app : http://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/ADukg/ and in the console you see correctly -0 as @JamesThorpe shows in the official doc

Comment: Define "returns". Do you mean by this "displays in the template"? If so, I guess it's because `toString()` is internally used there and it will strip the trailing `-` sign. Try it for yourself: `Math.ceil(-0.001).toString()`

Comment: ok, I see now, that it hasn't something to do with angular. More or less my problem is that if I type -0 into an variable that sould be displayed in html it just displays it as 0.

Comment: @mingos Thanks for pointing that out, following the spec through, `-0` converted to a string is [also explicitly defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type) as returning `"0"`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem... thank you very much!

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yep, and it's defined to convert `-0` to `"0"`. Quoting the document you linked: The abstract operation ToString converts a Number m to String format as follows: (...) 2. If m is +0 or −0, return the String "0".

Comment: @mingos Indeed.  Feel free to type up an answer along those lines - it was your comment about `toString()` that led me there.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the internals of Angular's template code, but I believe it uses `toString()` on the variables that are to be displayed inside the template.

`toString()` is defined to return the string `"0"` if used on the `Number` type with value `-0`. You can try this out for yourself:

```js
console.log(Math.ceil(-0.001).toString());
```

As @JamesThorpe mentioned in his comment, this behaviour is [explicitly defined in the ECMA2015 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type). Quoting the document:

> **7.1.12.1 ToString Applied to the Number Type**
>
> The abstract operation ToString converts a Number *m* to String format as follows:
>
> (...)
>
> 2. If *m* is **+0** or **−0**, return the String **`"0"`**.